How to set Chrome to always open PDF in the system viewer?
Google Chrome on Windows 11: when I click a PDF link, it opens a File Save dialog. How do I force it to open the PDF file  in the system default viewer (in my case it is Sumatra, set as the default viewer-- that is, when I launch a local PDF, it is opened in Sumatra.
Now, I want the same for PDF links in Chrome (not in Chrome's own window), without the need  for  me to choose a location to save it and to click on it  in that location?
I recall there used to be an option for this in Chrome's Settings, nut where is it?

Just do it through the properties window, it’s a single click. If double clicking doesn’t open a pdf then your file association is screwed up.

There WERE different past behaviours and at one time simply setting  chrome://plugins/ and disable "Chrome PDF viewer" was possible but Chrome keeps moving goal posts.
With current Chromiums unlike FireFox there is no native open in system by default. File Opener must be set once downloaded. IF Adobe acrobat is installed it will automatically reload the PDF into itself, but that is done by Adobe modifications to the system when Acrobat is installed.  SumatraPDF does not make such modifications, but simply registers as available as default reader.

You could continue using SumatraPDF 3.6 pre-Release in any latest version of Gecko/PaleMoon(Goanna)-based Desktop browsers there are a few independent from FireFox.
Like secure Current Basilisk (2024-09-13) or PaleMoon (33.3.1) or K-Meleon (24-09-14) with on/off control of JavaScript etc. The difference here is that the browser will export the download and may then call on SumatraPDF to load it and return it to the Browsers Frame as an external plug-in, the viewer could even be Mozilla PDF.js plug-in.
K-Meleon can use at least 3 plug-ins! Acrobat Reader, PDF.js and SumatraPDF but sporadically updated, currently 76.5.5 latest only 2 days old 2024-09-14 but more stable may be 2024-07-20.

The setting is almost hidden in latest Chrome and almost as obscure as in MS Edge it is
" Always download PDF files "

Under Privacy and Security expand this section

